# Django: redirect doesn't work as expected

Tags: django, redirect

I want to redirect the user if session_order_reference is empty. However, Django is still running till `i.ticket.event.currency` which brings an error `local variable 'currency' referenced before assignment`. I thought once I call redirect it will stop there and just redirects the user. Am I wrong there?

```
def checkout_page(request):
    session_order_reference = request.session.get('order_reference')
    if not request.session.get('order_reference'):
        redirect('website:index')  # TODO Marc: Better change to direct event link
    reserved_item = ReservedItem.objects.filter(order_reference=session_order_reference)
    d = {}
    total_amount = total_tax_amount = 0
    order_item_data = []

    for i in reserved_item:
        currency = i.ticket.event.currency
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect is a response, you need to return it:

```
if not request.session.get('order_reference'):
    return redirect('website:index')
```

Comment: Oh wow. Always these small but meaning full details I should know by now... now it works. Thank you Daniel!